# Impersonating wcf client in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, wcf

Assume we have a contract

```
public interface IService
{
    System.String DoSomethingUseful();
}
```

And need to call client from .aspx page

```
var client = new ServiceClient();
var result = client.DoSomethingUseful();
```

The problem is that only special user have rights on some actions inside "DoSomethingUseful" and i have to impersonate the pool with identity:

```
<identity impersonate="true" userName="domain\SecretUser" password="secretPass" />
```

Otherwise i'll get "Access Denied" exception on method call.

Is there another way to impersonate wcf client except impersonating the pool, maybe somewhere in bindings?

Comment: Or you can use impersonation in code: http://csharptuning.blogspot.ru/2007/06/impersonation-in-c.html
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10090/A-small-C-Class-for-impersonating-a-User lowlevel:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306158

Answer (score 0):

I would look at setting `ClientCredentials` - see  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms553830.aspx